# Label class for only one value based on Symbology Levels using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, symbology

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to label some point features that I have three levels for in symbology but I want to display the value on the label for only one of the three symbology levels at a time.

Is that possible?

My shapefile has three columns: `Well_ID`, `Zone`, and `WL2018`. The symbology is based off the `Zone`.

Using VBScript, I already have:

```
[Well_ID] & vbnewline & [WL2018].
```

What I want is for the labels for `WL2018` to only appear on points where the value for one zone is true. For example, I have three levels of symbology, `Alluvial`, `Interface`, and `Bedrock`. I want my map to have labels at each point for only the WL2018 Alluvial data, and not show the data for bedrock or interface.

[image: Symbology]

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the labels to be displayed from "SQL" in the labeling property.
Does it match what you want to do?

postscript:
I feel that setting a conditional expression for the label will solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Yes, sort of. But that gets rid of the entire label. I want the Well_ID labelled for all, but only the Zone labelled for some. When I do the SQL expression for Where Zone is equal to Interface, it gets rid of the labels for all the Well_ID that are not interface. I'd like to keep those.